# What DNS records are needed to point a domain to an IP address?

Tags: dns, domains

I have a newly registered domain `example.co.uk` which I have bought from 123-reg.co.uk and I want to point it to IP address `192.0.2.0` which is a VPS hosted by a different company.

What DNS records do I need to create on 123-reg.co.uk in order to point `example.co.uk` and `www.example.co.uk` to `192.0.2.0`? Is the following anywhere close to correct?

```
example.co.uk.    A       192.0.2.0
www               CNAME   example.co.uk
```

As usual, documentation is long on explanations but short on examples. The 123-reg.co.uk tech support just keep quoting parts of their "help" manual back at me.

Comment: In the second line provided, the name should end with a dot.

Answer (score 1):

That will do fine as long as you're happy for 123-reg.co.uk to act as the authoritative name server for the domain (which means that if their name servers go down, then your website is effectively offline), you don't care what happens to email sent to `@example.co.uk` email addresses, and you don't have an IPV6 address that you want to use as well.

Comment: Should the 2nd line have a . at the end of `example.co.uk`?

Comment: Yes it should have a period at the end. Otherwise the origin will get appended so what the above record without the period will be equivalent of www -> `example.co.uk.example.co.uk`. (Assuming the Origin is set to ice-hot.co.uk).

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the domain `example.co.uk` is available for purchase. You can check it from the below URL,
https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/cart.php?a=add&domain=register&query=example.co.uk

First, please verify your domain name.

After that check the NS record of the domain name `example.co.uk`. It should be set your domain registrar NS.

The following records are correct if you just want to point `example.co.uk` and `www.example.co.uk` to `192.0.2.0`.

```
example.co.uk.    A            192.0.2.0
www                CNAME   example.co.uk
```

If you have just updated the DNS record, please wait for the propagation.

Any changes in DNS records may take 12-24 hours to propagate globally.

You can verify the nameserver and A record from the below URL,
https://intodns.com/example.co.uk

Comment: This question is 10 years old so no longer needs personal help.  I changed it to use an example domain so that it is hopefully useful for others in the future.